# External DNS - All records are already up to date, there are no changes for the matching hosted zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubectl, amazon-eks, external-dns

I created an external-DNS on my cluster, but no records are getting created for alb endpoints. logs show ***"Skipping record because no hosted zone matching record DNS Name was detected All records are already up to date, there are no changes for the matching hosted zones"***

Here is my external DNS manifest: I followed this [tutorial][1]

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: external-dns
  namespace: test
  # If you're using Amazon EKS with IAM Roles for Service Accounts, specify the following annotation.
  # Otherwise, you may safely omit it.
  annotations:
    # Substitute your account ID and IAM service role name below.
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:role/ExternalDNSRole
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: external-dns
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["services", "endpoints", "pods"]
    verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
  - apiGroups: ["extensions", "networking.k8s.io"]
    resources: ["ingresses"]
    verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["nodes"]
    verbs: ["list", "watch"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: external-dns-viewer
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: external-dns
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: external-dns
    magento: test
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: external-dns
  magento: test
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: external-dns
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: external-dns
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: external-dns
      containers:
        - name: external-dns
          image: k8s.gcr.io/external-dns/external-dns:v0.7.3
          args:
            - --source=service
            - --source=ingress
            - --domain-filter=test.cloud
            - --provider=aws
            - --aws-prefer-cname
            # - --policy=upsert-only # would prevent ExternalDNS from deleting any records, omit to enable full synchronization
            - --aws-zone-type=public # only look at public hosted zones (valid values are public, private or no value for both)
            - --registry=txt
            - --txt-owner-id=XXXXX
            - --txt-prefix={{ test-frontend. }}
            - --log-level=debug
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 10m
              memory: 128Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 10m
              memory: 128Mi
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 65534 # For ExternalDNS to be able to read Kubernetes and AWS token files
```

[1]: http://%20https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/aws.md)

Following is service manifest:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "test-web"
  namespace: magento
  annotations:
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: test-frontend.test.cloud
  labels:
    app: test-web
    k8s-app: test
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "http"
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: test-web
```

And this is my ingress manifest:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: main
  namespace: magento
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: test.cloud
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:eu-west-2:342366666223132:certificate/aac2312b13231213a03-a2d3123123b-433312312324f-b2f9-058ca1213951f30
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": {"Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
  labels:
    app: test-web
spec:
  rules:
    - host: test-frontend.test.cloud
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: magento-web
              servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Were you ever able to find a resolution for this?

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: Does your hosted zone already have ARecord for `test.cloud` or `test-frontend.test.cloud`? I found that my external-dns service was skipping records that did not match `txt-owner-id`.